# landscape view in mobile

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have created a form where we have around 21 fields to be filled. when I viewed this form in mobile toggle, for portrait view its working fine, but for landscape view, The alignment getting disturb ,How can resolve this issue, any help much appreciated. Below I have added images.
for this I have used the lightning layout

[image: Landscape View Alignment]--

[image: Portrait View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify correct values for `small-device-size`, `medium-device-size` and `large-device-size`. Phone in tablet mode is considered as a `medium-device-size`. Useful info from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/documentation)

> Use the attributes of lightning-layout-item to configure the size of
> the layout item, and change how the layout is configured on different
> device sizes.
>
> The layout system is mobile-first. Typically, the small-device-size
> attribute indicates a smart phone, medium-device-size indicates a
> tablet, and large-device-size indicates a desktop or larger device.
>
> If you specify the small-device-size, medium-device-size, or
> large-device-size attributes, you must also specify the size
> attribute.
>
> If you specify the size and small-device-size attributes, the size
> attribute applies to small mobile phones, and the small-device-size
> applies to smart phones. The device sizing attributes are additive and
> apply to devices of the specified size and larger. For example, if you
> set medium-device-size=10 and don't set large-device-size, then the
> medium-device-size setting applies to tablets, desktops, and larger
> devices. You'd also have to set size to apply to devices smaller than
> tablets.

---

from SLDS [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/#overview) `medium-size` is screen width 768px and higher

you should have something like as the outer component for each form element:

```
<lightning-layout-item
    size=6
    large-device-size=2
    medium-device-size=4
    small-device-size=6>
<!-- INPUT HERE -->
</lightning-layout-item>
```

Comment: Ok, for desktops It should show 6 fields in a row and for mobile it should show only 2 fields in a row, How can I give the size for above requirements @Oleksandr Berehovskyi--could you please suggest me something on this.

Comment: @user97539 default size of the layout is 12 items, so if you want to have 6 fields in a row, the size of each should be 2, if 2 fields in a row - the size of each is 6.

Comment: this form opens up in a modal,When view the same in Iphone lanscape view, the full modal is not opening , I mean the below part in clipping for every iphone device only. I could not figure out what exactly is the issue?Any help much appreciated